# breeze - saving after loaded by stored procedure

Tags: breeze

I have a grid loaded with angular function calling stored procedure and i want to add to the grid a textbox and save it with breeze (part of the saving - insert will be pulling columns from the grid loaded by the sp) .  how can i do that?

here is the angular (in my controller) used for loading the grid:

```
    $scope.loadSales = function () {
        $scope.pageLoaded = false;
    PService.SalesStatus($scope.filter).then(function (data) {
        $scope.lists = data;
        $scope.getcount= data.length;               
        $scope.pageLoaded = true;                
    });
}
```

here is my html of the grid:

```
 <md-content ng-controller="ListCtrl" >
                <md-tabs>              
                    <md-tab label="{{getcount}}">
                        <table>
                            <tr> 
                                <td width="10%">Not Sold:</td>
                                <td width="40%">
                                    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="filter.NotSold">
                                        <option value=0>no</option>
                                        <option value=1>yes</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>    
                        </table>                                              

                        <md-button ng-click="loadSales()">Load Report</md-button>
                        <md-button ng-click="Save()">Save</md-button>

                        <div style="overflow: auto; font-size: 12px;width: 100%;">      
                            <table style="font-size: 12px">

                                <tr ng-repeat="item in lists | limitTo:1" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 1000, 'blur': 0} }">
                                    <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
                                        <span>
                                            <label style="color: black">{{key}} </label>
                                        </span>


                                    </td>
                                    <td>Qty to Save </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat="item in lists" ng-init="filter">
                                    <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">

                                        <span> <label>{{val}} </label></span></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" name="saveForLater" ng-model="saveQty" /> </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </div>

                    </md-tab>
                </md-tabs>
            </md-content>
```

here is the function that calls the c# stored procedure in my service:

```
function SalesStatus(filter) {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/Services/SalesStatus',
        params: {notSold: filter.notSold }
    }).then(function (result)
    { return result.data; })
};
```

Comment: It'll be helpful if you show us the code.

Comment: @TravisSchettler - i updated my post with some code. i have breeze all set up already also, just wondering how i can use it with the current set up...  i want to use breeze to save the extra cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LisaSolomon, starting from here, you're probably better off writing a standard webapi to do the update.  Your breeze entities pulled from a stored procedure are not updateable and, not knowing the underlying table structure that informs you stored procedure, there is no way to suggest a breeze.js-way of updating/inserting the property that you want to manage.  My approach has always been that if I can't represent the model organically on the client side, then I don't want to try to update it organically using breeze.

Comment: ok, thanks. but i may have 2 options then.  Should I (A) change my stored proc to a view (somehow) and then can use it in breeze to return my data and then i can use breeze to update my extra td cell , right?  or (b) when you say write standard webapi - translates to writing a stored proc to update/insert this new td cell/field and call it as i have the first stored proc?

Comment: also, what about making it a table scalared function. does breeze like that?

Comment: As I understand it, Breeze will interact with any object in your model as if it is a table.  Or, actually, in the same way that entity framework does.  If the entity that breeze is materializing on the client has a primary key and is related in known ways to the rest of your model and can be updated with standard data modification syntax within entity framework, it should work.  By standard webapi, I mean an endpoint that you directly use $http to update/insert the value rather than breeze.  Breeze is designed to work with complete entities.

Comment: I actually don't think I can make it into a view.  But this edited field will actually also be retrieved as well.  I've already created models and mappings for it.  I just need to pull 1 of the fields returned by the sp for the new entity and then I would be good.  Can I do that somehow?  Someone at work told me that I could do it but I'd need to load it twice.  not sure what that means...

Comment: Yeh, I think I understand what you're saying.  If the entity you're trying to update is Widget and the stored procedure kives you the key to the entity, then once the value is updates, you can execute and EntityQuery that pulls the specific Widget, updates it, and then saves changes.  You cannot pull just updated column of Widget, because that would be a projection query in Breeze, which leaves the returned entities and untracked and non-updateable

Comment: I'm glad you understand me, but I don't understand you.  So what should I do?  How can I go about easily implimenting this and calling savechanges()?

Comment: Okay, so you have the change that needs to be made, presumably you have or can easily find the key to the entity you want to change.  If this is true, create an EntityQuery.('Widgets').where('WidgetId','eq',widgetIdThatIKnow).  When you execute that query, you will retrieve the entity that you want to update.  Make the change to that entity, and then call saveChanges().